# ZeroMQ PUB/SUB example won't work from EC2 to private IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, zeromq

I am a noob to zeromq and I'm trying to use it to message from an Ubuntu 12.04 micro instance on AWS to my home PC. Here is the Subscriber code which I run on my home pc under msvc++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "zmq.hpp"

static std::string s_recv (zmq::socket_t &socket) {
    zmq::message_t message;
    socket.recv(&message);
    return std::string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size()-1);
}

int main () {
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);

std::cout << "Connecting to port 5556..." << std::endl;
subscriber.connect("tcp://ec2-23-22-38-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5556");
const char *filter ="Sending ";

subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter ,strlen(filter));

int update_nbr=0;
for (update_nbr=0; update_nbr<100; update_nbr++){
    zmq::message_t update;
    std::string msg_s=s_recv(subscriber);
    std::cout<<"Received something..."<<msg_s<<std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

and here is the publisher code I am running on the AWS instance, compiled by g++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "zmq.hpp"

static std::string s_recv (zmq::socket_t &socket) {

zmq::message_t message;
socket.recv(&message);

return std::string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size()-1);
}

int main () {
//  Prepare our context and socket
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);

std::cout << "Binding to port 5556..." << std::endl;


publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");

int cnt =0;
while(1){


    char buffer[30];
    int msgn=0;
    msgn=snprintf(buffer, 30, "Sending number %d", cnt);
    std::cout<<buffer<<std::endl;
    zmq::message_t message(30);
    memcpy((void*) message.data(), buffer,30);

    publisher.send(message);

    sleep(1);
    cnt++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Both computers have version  ZeroMQ 3.2.3 installed.

When I run both locally on the AWS instance (replacing the tcp address as "tcp://localhost:5556") it works fine and same when both are on my home-pc however nothing happens when I run them on different IP addresses.

Am I using the wrong address for the amazon instance? Is it formatted wrongly? I can't help but feel there is just something really basic that I'm doing wrong because this is all pretty new to me. If you need any more info let me know. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does your security group have port 5556 opened correctly?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I added a TCP rule to my security group 0.0.0.0/0, ports 5000-6000, and restarted the instance and it works now. Thanks.